# Reference for rigorous second quantization

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, mp.mathematical-physics

I'd like to get acquainted with the basics of mathematical rigorous second quantization, so I'm looking for an adequate reference on this subject. I've a background in quantum mechanics, but I don't know much on quantum field thery (I don't know to what extent it is necessary to understand second quantization). The point is: my research area is rigorous statistical mechanics, so I don't intend to become an expert on the subject, but I need to understand at least the basics. The only reference I know is [The Method of second quantization](https://www.elsevier.com/books/the-method-of-second-quantization/berazin/978-0-12-089450-5) by F. Berezin. So far, I've just skimmed the book and it seems incredibly well-written, but it is obviously an old book and I feel it is not very modern concerning its mathematics: I'd be happier to find a more technical exposition, using modern functional analysis. However, I don't know if this reasoning is just a reflection of the fact that I know hardly nothing on the subject. So I ask: is Berezin's book the best place to start? Are there other (more technical, maybe) references on the subject? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

§X.7 of Reed & Simon's *Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics v.2* (Academic Press, 1975) starts out with the epigraph *First quantization is a mystery, but second quantization is a functor. E. Nelson*. It's pretty rigorous.

Comment: Great! I love these collection and I pretty much like everything Reed and Simon write. This sounds perfect!

Answer (score 1):

One book which may be useful to you is by Edson De Faria's: [Mathematical aspects of QFT](https://www.academia.edu/31316572/Mathematical_aspects_of_quantum_field_theory).

The tract has been written by someone who definitely has a strong background in physics but is nevertheless a mathematician (former student of the famous geometer Dennis Purnell Sullivan). As you may know, there are different ways to introduce QFT, one being via **Lagrangian densities**, another via the **Fock space** (and there are others, for instance the categorical approach). This text does not cover all of them, but it is definitely something a math-oriented fellow can enjoy

Comment: Great answer! Thank you so much! I'll definitely read Edson's book. Btw, what's your opinion on Dimock's book "Quantum Mechanics and Quantum Field Theory"? It seems very good too.

Comment: simple answer: I have no opinion, because I have not read it ! But now I am going to check it out... as an aside, I know what I would LOVE to see in a book on QFT: some articulated discussion on how the different presentations are related to one another.  Never seen anything like it..

Comment: PS I knew Edson quite well: we were writing our dissertations in the same crammed room some centuries ago. If you read the book and wish to reach out to him, do it: Edson is a very nice fellow,

Comment: Mirco, that's really nice. I took a course many years ago with him as well. Very nice professor, indeed.

Comment: the world is small indeed.... if you catch up with Edson send him the best from the crazy italian :)

Comment: Nice! I'll keep that in mind!